# Pdfjs: messy characters

Tags: pdf.js

I used [pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to display pdf files in browsers. However, some files just not display well. For example, [all.pdf](http://www.cyut.edu.tw/~yltang/all.pdf) shows messy in [pdfjs-all.html](http://www.cyut.edu.tw/~yltang/pdfjs-all.html). But I used [PdfShuffle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/) to crop the first two page of `all.pdf` and save them to [2.pdf](http://www.cyut.edu.tw/~yltang/2.pdf). Then it displays very well using [pdfjs-2.html](http://www.cyut.edu.tw/~yltang/pdfjs-2.html).

The only difference between `pdfjs-all.html` and `pdfjs-2.html` is the `url`. So, what's the problem? Is it because of the pdf file or the pdfjs?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried encoding your URL and then inputting to the pdfjs algorithm?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but I don't quite get your point. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and resolved it by setting `textLayerMode: TEXT_LAYER_MODE`, inside  `new PDFJS.PDFViewer({})`.

The messy text is now gone and the pdf looks normal.